# git clone: I get a strange authentication error

Tags: git, github

I'm admin in a private github repo. Since this morning, when I try to clone that repo I get:

```
git clone https://github.com/myblabla/blabla.git
Cloning into 'blabla'...
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ENOENT /run/user/1000/vscode-git-fa9d1b661a.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',

  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/1000/vscode-git-fa9d1b661a.sock'
}
Missing or invalid credentials.
Error: connect ENOENT /run/user/1000/vscode-git-fa9d1b661a.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/1000/vscode-git-fa9d1b661a.sock'
}
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for
```

I never had that before. What's the fix?

When I do:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: It literally means the git credentials supplied (or not) are invalid. This may help: https://www.shellhacks.com/git-config-username-password-store-credentials/

Comment: @Stuart I don't think it means that, actually. I think it means that git is unable to connect to the authentication socket provided by vscode, so it's failing to acquire auth credentials. Unfortunately, I'm not a vscode user and I can't offer suggestions beyond "have you tried restarting vscode?".

Comment: I typing these things in the vscode terminal. As if it were a bash. Why is VScode even involved in this?

Comment: Note that you're explicitly calling for cloning via HTTPS, not SSH (`https://...`). How VSCode gets in the way here, I have no idea, though.

Comment: Had the same problem, reinitated vscode: "problem fixed".

Comment: but how does ones "reinitiate" vscode

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently, it's vscode's virtual terminal Easter egg. When I type the git clone command in a proper terminal (not the emulator in vs), it works as usual.

Comment: true, opening a new terminal in VSCode solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 29):

Try to open a new terminal in your VSCode, this may solve your problem.

Comment: This worked for me. Accepted answer does not speak to how to solve it. Restarting VSCode did not work, but closing and re-opening the built-in terminal did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Close the **VS-Code** and open again

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, it was caused by me using a terminal multiplexor on my Linux machine, connecting to it via VSCode's remote SSH and then trying to commit from a regular SSH connection which was also connecting through the terminal multiplexor.

Logging out the multiplexor reset things.

So be careful if you're using something like Tmux on the remote machine and access it inside the VSCode terminal, it seems to confuse git.

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this problem by doing what I was trying to do from the terminal instead.

For me, it was an authentication error due to something with VSCode.

I faced the same problem earlier today.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30690780)